# AJAX calling Django view function not only once but for previous attempts as well

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a code that should delete a list item.

```
        // Triggers when the item "element_to_click" is double clicked and calls the 
        // function named show_hide_function()

        $( element_to_click ).one('dblclick', function(e) {
          show_hide_function(input_mt_key, update_form_mt, input_mt, button_text, 
          csrfmiddlewaretoken)});
    
  
       // Creates a button to delete the selected item, then calls delete_function()
       
       function show_hide_function(input_key, form, input, button_text, csrf_token){
           const del_btn = document.createElement("button")
           del_btn.name="my_del_btn"
           form.appendChild(del_btn);
           const button_text_del = document.createTextNode("X")
           del_btn.appendChild(button_text_del)
           del_btn.setAttribute("class", "update_delete_buttons")
    
        // On click on del_btn, calls the function named delete_function()
        $( del_btn ).on('click', function(e) {
            delete_function(input_key,csrf_token)});
        };
    
   
       // Sends a form to backend (django) and on success, calls another function 
       // named jsonToDict() which I believe, is not part of the problem. So I don't 
       // include it here.
       function delete_function(input_key, csrf_token){
        $(document).on('submit' , function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/posted/delete/',
                data:{
                item_id:input_key.value,
                projectURL: projectURL_,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken:csrf_token,
                },
                success: function (data){
                    jsonToDict(data, "update_delete_form")
                }; 
              });
            });
           };
```

And simplified version of my django view function looks like this:

```
def deleteDictionary(request):
   print("called")
   if request.method == 'POST':
       var2 = request.POST['item_id']
       projectURL = request.POST['projectURL']
       value_holder = Task.objects.filter(taskID=var2).values_list('taskIdentifier')
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      response_data = json.dumps(jsonString)
      return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')
   else:
       pass
```

This is how my items look
[image]

This is how they look on double click:
[image]

When I delete first item, I get no error. When I do the same thing for the second item (without refreshing the page), it also gets deleted, but I get the following error on frontend:
[image]

I go back to server side and check whats going on, I see that on click onto delete button of second item, the view function is called twice (function prints "called" twice.) and naturally, it creates problem for the rest of the code which I didn't include here, since I think that is not the problem (the input provided by form should be added into a list, and then that list is being worked. Since function is called twice, it creates an empty list and function gives an error).
Moreover, when I refresh the page and delete 3 items, it creates that error twice (first call works fine, second and third creates error, meaning, django view function is called 2 times and 3 times respectively)
I think you get the idea.
So somehow, AJAX calls my django view function n times where n is the item number I attempt to delete, even tho I click on different items' delete button...

In the past, I didn't have these event listeners and functions. I had my AJAX form without being in a function and it worked perfectly. Now that I want it to work for each item separately, it gives this error.

What I tried so far:
I checked if the delete_function() function is called twice when I click on second item's delete button. The answer is NO. Everything you see in JS code above is called only once. But somehow AJAX remembers the previous attempts and calls the django view function for those attempts too.

I'd like to underline that the view function works fine. If I tried to delete 5 items, all 5 items are deleted regardless of the function creating an error or not. But since function is called multiple times unnecessarily, it slows my code dramatically.

Short version of my question is, how can I avoid AJAX to submit the form for previous attempts.

Comment: did you return any JSON response from view?

Comment: Yes I did, my view function ends with  "return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type='application/json')". And the success function from AJAX receives that, and calls the jsonToDict() function without any problem. For clarification, I just added that part to code above.